# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Azure AD Authentication throws OptionsValidationException

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use Azure Active Directory to handle authentication on a web app. However, when I try to hit an action with the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizeattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1), the app throws a [`OptionsValidationException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.optionsvalidationexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1). With the following error:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsValidationException: The 'Instance' option must be provided.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI.AzureADOpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration.Configure(String name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Get>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext context, String authenticationScheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.ChallengeAsync(AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

I can't figure out what is causing this. Here's the code:

**Add a package reference to [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI/) version 3.1.1.**

#### Startup Class

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = "<client_id_goes_here>";
            options.TenantId = "<tenant_id_goes_here>";
        });

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapControllers());
}
```

#### Home Controller

Using only one controller.

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public string Index() => "Hello Anonymous User!";

    [Route("restricted")]
    [Authorize]
    public string Restricted() => $"Hello, {User.Identity.Name}.";
}
```

When you run the app and hit the Index action, you get the excepted output:

```
Hello Anonymous User!
```

When you hit the `/restricted` endpoint, then the exception is thrown.

Comment: Have you tried adding `app.UseAuthentication()` in your `configure` method - just before `app.UseAuthorization()`?

Comment: @SimplyGed Yes, it has the same results.

Comment: Have you referred to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-sign-user-app-configuration?tabs=aspnetcore

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You didn't provide several configrations that `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` needed in Azure AD authentication , such as `Instance`,`CallbackPath`. You can modify your codes as below :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

Then in `appsettings.json` ,adding bleow configration :

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxx-a2dd-4fde-bf8f-f75ab18b21ac",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxx-a9bb-4722-b615-6dcbdc646326",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

Of course , you should provide the real domian/tenant/clientid in Azure portal and register `https://localhost:xxx/signin-oidc` as redirect url in portal .

Another way is use the Azure AD authentication  template : New ASP.NET Core application -->Choose MVC/Razor template -->change authentication-->Work or School Account -->choose your tenant and the template will help config your application to implement Azure AD authentication .

Comment: This worked! I always thought that the other fields weren't required or they would have default values. I have used Open ID Connect with Azure AD and the only fields that I had to provide were Client ID and Authority.

Comment: @JosseanYamil , authority is instance+tenant in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI` . Please consider to mark the reply as answer which may help others who meet same problem .

Comment: I was setting up a new application, using a previous one as an example that I had set up months prior. It turns out I had forgotten to add the `AzureAd` section to the `appsettings.json` file.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error for my Project. I figured out that the Client ID was not injected to the Appsettings variable as a part of Azure DevOps Pipeline deployment. As a result the Kubernetes pods were missing the Azure AD variables. Tweaking the secrets.yaml in Azure Devops solved the problem.