# ASP.Net 6.0 Web API: Error <IDW10106: The 'Instance' option must be provided> when trying to use IConfiguration in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have currently an API controller looking like this:

```
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger)
    {
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I have security settings in programm.cs like that:

```
// Microsoft Identity Authentication
var jwtAuthentication = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
_ = jwtAuthentication.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
_ = jwtAuthentication.AddAppServicesAuthentication();
...
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

This all works fine so far. But when I now try to add IConfiguration parameter to the controller like this:

```
    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger, IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
    }
```

A call to any operation of that controller ends with this exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: IDW10106: The 'Instance' option must be
> provided.     at
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.MergedOptionsValidation.Validate(MergedOptions
> options)    at
> Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthenticationBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(JwtBearerOptions
> options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IOptionsMonitor`1 mergedOptionsMonitor, IOptionsMonitor`1 msIdOptionsMonitor, IOptions`1 msIdOptions)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigureNamedOptions`5.Configure(String
> name, TOptions options)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory`1.Create(String name)    at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0()
> at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)    at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper
> executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)    at
> System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()    at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.GetOrAdd(String name, Func`1 createOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsMonitor`1.Get(String name)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme
> scheme, HttpContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandlerProvider.GetHandlerAsync(HttpContext
> context, String authenticationScheme)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext)    at
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware.InvokeInternal(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

As soon as I disable the security settings, all works fine again. In a way it smells, that the conroller construction is done differently when security settings are in place, and then the IConfiguration parameter is somehow a problem ...

What do I have to change to make the controller run with both parameters ILogger and IConfiguration togheter with the given security settings?

Comment: I'm confused., something quite strange happend over night. I led Visual Studio open and this morning, when I wanted to start further investigation into the problem - it was solved. All runs fine with Authorization toghether with IConfiguration parameter in the controller. However, probably I changed one little tiny thing but cannot see what it would be ... If I find out, I will report here - let's hope the solved situation remains like that ;)

Comment: Oh dear, I found it out. I had accidentially messed up the appsettings.json (the same problem has here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178378/asp-net-core-3-1-azure-ad-authentication-throws-optionsvalidationexception) and then fixed it without relating it to the problem I was fighting with - it had nothing to do at all with the new IConfiguration parameter ... silly me -.-